# Call a class method like a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl

I'm using SDL, but i accept any solution with other libraries if it is possible (pthread, boost_thread...).
I have a class:

```
class c_image
{
    public:
        bool _flag_thread;
        int  _id;
        void load (void);
    private:
        int thread_func (void*);
}

c_image::load (void)
{
    SDL_Thread* thread_1;
    if (flag_thread)
        thread_1 = SDL_CreateThread (c_image::thread_func, NULL);
    else
        thread_func (NULL);
}

c_image::thread_func (void* data)
{
    _id = 1;
    ....
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that if `flag_thread` is false, it execute `thread_func` like a normal function and it works fine, but if `flag_thread` is true, i need that call in a different thread and i have no idea how to make it. The line of `SDL_CreateThread` return an error. I need the thread of the method because inside the `thread_func` i need to modify elements like `_id` that is a member of the class, and if i make the thread outside of the class i don't have access to `_id`.

Thanks.

Edit:
This is how I have it now, and not find a way to make it work:

```
class c_image
{
    public:
        bool _flag_thread;
        int  _id;
        void load (void);
    private:
        static int thread_func_wrapper (void* data);
        int thread_func (void);
}

void c_image::load (void)
{
    SDL_Thread* thread_1;
    if (flag_thread)
        thread_1 = SDL_CreateThread (thread_func_wrapper, NULL, this);
    else
        thread_func();
}

int c_image::thread_func_wrapper (void* data)
{
    c_image* self = static_cast<c_image*>(data);
    return self->thread_func();
}

int c_image::thread_func (void)
{
    printf ("id: %d", _id);
    ....
    return 0;
}
```

Now it seems it work fine. I will continue doing tests. Thanks you very much!

Comment: Are you getting an error from the compiler? If so, what error?

Comment: The compiler return: error: invalid cast from type ‘int (c_image::*)(void*)’ to type ‘int*’

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `SDL_CreateThread` is a "C" style interface, so it can't take a `std::function` or similar type function object. Instead, you need to create a static function that takes a pointer to the reference as the `void *data` pointer:

```
class c_image
{
  ... 
  static void thread_func_wrapper(void *data);

  int thread_func(void);
};


int c_image::thread_func_wrapper(void *data)
{
   c_image* self = static_cast<c_image*>(data);
   return self->thread_func();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying what you wrote and now it compile, but when execute the thread return a segmentation fault. In the debugger i see the public member _id and others are empty and _id could be have another value that i set before.

Comment: Yes, you will need `SDL_CreateThread (c_image::thread_func, NULL, this);` as well - otherwise it will use some "random stuff" as the `self` pointer, which probably won't work.

Comment: Also note that I just changed the `void` in the return type to `int` - which is what `SDL_CreateThread` expects.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't know where i need to put `SDL_CreateThread` and `thread_func_wrapper`, i'm confused, sorry.

Comment: SDL_createThread goes where it is now. But you call it with `SDL_createThread(thread_func_wrapper, NULL, this)`. Sorry, I messed up my comment above, forgot to change `thread_func` to `thread_func_wrapper`.

Comment: Edited above. I don't find solution.

Comment: You missed out `static` on the declaration of `thread_func_wrapper`. This makes a difference, because a static function doesn't have a hidden `this` argument (which is why you have to pass `this` as the third argument in the CreateThread call)

Comment: I'm trying with `static int` and nothing: cannot declare member function ‘static int c_image::thread_func_wrapper(void*)’ to have static linkage [-fpermissive].

Comment: No, the `static` needs to go in the class declaration of the function, not in the definition outside of the class.